# initialize array of pointer and matrix

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, matrix, initialization

I want to initialize array of pointer.(not a normal array) But this doesn't work.

```
int* arr = new int [5];
arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Also I don't want to do it like this:(Because if the size changes I have to change the code)

```
arr[0] = 1; arr[1] = 2; ...
```

Is there an easy way to do this? what about a matrix?

```
int** mat = ...
mat = { {1,2} , {3,4} }
```

And also I don't want initialize like this: (Because when I want to pass the matrix to a function there are some limits (For example: If size changes, I have to change function defenition))

```
int mat[2][2] = { {1,2} , {3,4} };
```

Comment: Why not `std::vector<int> arr = {1,2,3,4,5}` or `std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 2>` if the size is known at compile time instead of using raw arrays?

Comment: You can use template functions to auto-deduce the array size. As in `template<size_t R, size_t C> void f(std::array<std::array<int, C>, R> const&) { ... }`

Comment: @CoryKramer 1-Question limitations 2-I wanted to know there is a way to do this by using raw array or not :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write for example

```
int* arr = new int [5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Or for example you could use the algorithm `std::iota` like

```
int* arr = new int [5];
std::iota( arr, arr + 5, 1 );
```

or some other algorithm as for example `std::fill` or `std::generate`.

If the array will be reallocated then it is much better in this case to use the standard container `std::vector<int>`.

> (For example: If size changes, I have to change function defenition))

You can define the function as a template function where the size of an array will be a template non-type parameter.

Comment: That's it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you ***really*** want to dynamically create an array yourself then do what @Vlad from Moscow recommends:

`int* arr = new int [5] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`

or:

```cpp
int* arr = new int [5];
std::iota( arr, arr + 5, 1 ); // also std::fill or std::generate
```

But, 99% of the time, using `std::vector` is almost better every way.

Your code would look like this:

```cpp
std::vector<int> arr{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
// if you know the size of the array at runtime, then do this
arr.resize(5 /* size of the array at runtime */)
```

Even better, if you know the size of the array at compile time then `std::array` is your best friend.

`std::array<int, 5 /* size of the array at compile time */> arr{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using std::make_unique to avoid new/delete.
However as you can see, the array size must be manually maintained.
So you're still better of using std::vector or std::array

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

// allocate with make_unqiue and initialize from list
template<typename type_t, std::size_t N>
auto make_array(const type_t (&values)[N])
{
    std::unique_ptr<type_t[]> array_ptr = std::make_unique<type_t[]>(N);
    for (std::size_t n = 0; n < N; ++n) array_ptr[n] = values[n];
    return array_ptr;
}

int main() 
{
    auto array_ptr = make_array({ 1,2,3,4,5 });

    for (std::size_t n = 0; n < 5; ++n)
    {
        std::cout << array_ptr[n] << " ";
    }

    // std::unique_ptr will take care of deleting the memory
}
```